# Jquery: How do i change the content of a specific div in a cell of a grid?

Tags: jquery

Currently i am using this to modify the "html" of a specific "column/cell" by finding the "td" of the "grid" at specific "rows".

```
$("#VGrid1_MainGrid tr:nth-child(" + iRowNumberGrid + ")").find('td').eq(26).html("HTMLHERE");
```

After that is done, how do I [ (a) access, (b) modify ] the individual "div1/div2" content that is in it for the "Grid" at particular "row" and "column"? RowNumber = 2, column = 26

```
<td>
<div class="myclass">
      <div id="div1">Access content</div>
      <div id="div2">Add/Modify content</div>
</div>
<td>
```

Thanks to all for the answer. I like best is this with just a single line.

```
$("#VGrid1_MainGrid tr:nth-child(" + iRowNumberGrid + ")").find('td').eq(26).find('#div1').html('stuffhere');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var td = $("#VGrid1_MainGrid tr:nth-child(" + iRowNumberGrid + ")").find('td').eq(26);
td.html("HTMLHERE");
$("#div1", td).html("foo");
$("#div2", td).html("bar");
```

Comment: Can you also put a jQuery object in the jQuery selector as the second argument? I thought it had to be a normal object (e.g. `this`).

Comment: @Marnix the context of the selector can be a jQuery object, a DOM element or a document. In this case td is a jQuery object. More info is available here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1

Answer (score 0):

Do not mess with the 4. row 26. column. This is a bad development practice. Instead you should give an id or class to exact column then select it with jQuery and do what you want to do. such as

```
var col = $('#row4column26'); // this will select you 26th column at 4th row 
col.find('#div1').html('HTMLHERE'); // select the div1 in the column and change its content
col.find(('#div2').html('HTMLHERE'); // the same for div2
```

Comment: i don't quite get you. Do you mean if i have a grid that when is generated in html, each of the columns has to have its individual id?

Comment: Actually, I dont mean give an id or class to each cell and row, I mean specialize the elements that you want to deal with jQuery by giving an id or class to easily modify its content by selecting a simple jQuery $ query. Then you go for other stuff

Answer (score 0):

When you have your element at the specified index:

```
$("#VGrid1_MainGrid tr:nth-child(" + iRowNumberGrid + ")").find('td').eq(26)
```

You can use `this` to access something inside. Like so:

```
$("#VGrid1_MainGrid tr:nth-child(" + iRowNumberGrid + ")").find('td').eq(26).each(function()
{
    $(this).html("HTMLHERE");
    $('#div1',this).doSomething();
});
```

Or even make your own selector a bit shorter:

```
$("#VGrid1_MainGrid tr:nth-child(" + iRowNumberGrid + ") td").eq(26).each(function()
{
    $(this).html("HTMLHERE");
    $(this).find('#div1').doSomething();
}
```

Comment: Using the .each() function for a selector which will only ever return 1 object seems a little convoluted.

Comment: @Rory: How would you say: do 2 things after one another without using `each`?

Comment: @Marnix In the example I posted I assigned the jQuery object which the selector returns to a variable. This can then be used as many times as needed.

Comment: @Rory: yes ok, that's possible too. But still, I don't see the problem of using each.

Comment: @Marnix The .eq() function will only ever return 1 item. Therefore your each loop would only consist of one iteration. I guess I was just being picky :)

Comment: @Rory: yes I think so too, because a forloop for one element is still O(1). ;)

Answer (score 0):

When you have already found the column the divs are in (your code above) you could just use .find('#div1') on the jQuery object of the column to retrieve the div and modify it with .html('stuffhere')

Comment: Does this work? $("#VGrid1_MainGrid tr:nth-child(" + iRowNumberGrid + ")").find('td').eq(26).find('#div1').html('stuffhere');

Comment: I tried to add a vote to this but it says i don't have enough reputation.